# Pass Interface to a generic attribute of a class in C#?

Tags: c#, generics

When a do this:

```
public class ball {
    ITeste<IItem> Teste{ get; set; }
}
```

I got the error:

> 'IItem' must be a non-abstract type with a public parameterless
>   constructor in order to use it as parameter 'T' in the generic type or
>   method

ITeste:

```
public interface ITeste<T> 
        where T : IItem, IEquatable<T>, new()
{
    //ITeste code
}
```

IItem:

```
public interface IItem : IEquatable<IItem>
{
    //IItem Code
}
```

It seems to be a simple question, but I could not find the answer. Any help it would be appreciated.

Comment: Well yes, you can't use `IItem` as a type argument for `ITeste`, because it doesn't satisfy the constraints you've expressed on `T` in `ITeste`. Put it this way - you can't write `new IItem()` because it's an interface...

Comment: Thanks for the answer Jon, I didn't see that. =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove new() from the constraints for ITeste

ITeste:

```
public interface ITeste<T>where T : IItem, IEquatable<T>
{
    //ITeste code
}
```